# Save Cycles Materials as Open Shading Language file

Tags: cycles-render-engine, materials, shaders, osl

we currently work on a project, where we want to use the Open Shading Language to reuse shaders and materials in other programs/renderers (who also support OSL like Arnold)
For that it would be great to write a osl-file out of a cycles material.

I found a plugin who creates an xml file from your cycles material containing osl
http://peter.cassetta.info/material-library/
but that's not platform independent.
Is there any posibility to save all cycles nodes from a material as an osl-file, without the need of scripting shaders?

Cheers Martin

Answer (score 2):

Currently this is not possible.

Gladly Blender is OpenSource and all OSL files for OSL supported nodes can be found in the git repo https://git.blender.org/gitweb/gitweb.cgi/blender.git/tree/HEAD:/intern/cycles/kernel/shaders

There are some nodes that are Cycles specific and will not be able to run correctly in other software packages as needed variables/context might not exists in those packages or named differently.

But it should be possible to create an overall function for your Material to simulate a Cycles material graph to a certain extend.